# Semi-generic function

Tags: c++, generics, function

I have a bunch of overloaded functions that operate on certain data types such as int, double and strings. Most of these functions perform the same action, where only a specific set of data types are allowed. That means I cannot create a simple generic template function as I lose type safety (and potentially incurring a run-time problem for validation within the function).

Is it possible to create a "semi-generic compile time type safe function"? If so, how? If not, is this something that will come up in C++0x?

An (non-valid) idea;

```
template <typename T, restrict: int, std::string >
void foo(T bar);
...
foo((int)0); // OK
foo((std::string)"foobar"); // OK
foo((double)0.0); // Compile Error
```

Note: I realize I could create a class that has overloaded constructors and assignment operators and pass a variable of that class instead to the function.

Comment: I think the assumption that you wouldn't have type safety without the restriction is somewhat suspicious. In addition, types are definitely not checked at runtime.

Comment: UncleBens: There's "no type safety" in so far that the example above for doubles would compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sfinae

```
template<typename> struct restrict { };
template<> struct restrict<string> { typedef void type; };
template<> struct restrict<int> { typedef void type; };

template <typename T>
typename restrict<T>::type foo(T bar);
```

That `foo` will only be able to accept `string` or `int` for `T`. No hard compile time error occurs if you call `foo(0.f)`, but rather if there is another function that accepts the argument, that one is taken instead.

Comment: Posted code does not even compile in VC++9. ("too few template arguments" on second line [among other errors])

Comment: I can't edit your code, but adding template <> before "struct restrict..." makes this work. Template vodoo..

Comment: Oops, i'm sorry i was asleep when i wrote that.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a "private" templatized function that is never exposed to the outside, and call it from your "safe" overloads.

By the way, usually there's the problem with exposing directly the templatized version: if the passed type isn't ok for it, a compilation error will be issued (unless you know your algorithm may expose subtle bugs with some data types).

Comment: You should take into account implicit conversions. Careful if you have an overload `foo(double)` but want to disable it for all integer types etc.

Comment: @UncleBens: yes, you're right. @Fredrik Ullner: what's the problem? Just create the template version only in the .cpp (calling it in a slightly different manner), and leave only the overloads in the .hpp (or .h) to be used from other compilation units.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit ugly solution, but functors could be an option:

```
class foo {
   void operator()(double); // disable double type
public:
   template<typename T>
   void operator ()(T bar) {
      // do something
   }
};

void test() {
   foo()(3); // compiles
   foo()(2.3); // error
}
```

Edit: I *inversed* my solution

```
class foo {
   template<typename T>
   void operator ()(T bar, void* dummy) {
     // do something
   }
public:
   // `int` is allowed
   void operator ()(int i) {
      operator ()(i, 0);
   }
};

foo()(2.3); // unfortunately, compiles
foo()(3); // compiles
foo()("hi"); // error
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but that would mean one would need to think out all potential data types that are invalid... Of which there are a (practical) infinite number..

Answer (score 0):

You could probably work with templates specializations for the "restricted" types you want to allow. For all other types, you don't provide a template specialization so the generic "basic" template would be used. There you could use something like BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to throw a compile error.

Here some pseudo-code to clarify my idea:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T bar) {BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(FALSE);}

template<> // specialized for double
void foo(double bar) {do_something_useful(bar);};
```

Comment: I can't find the proper documentation for the "typename: specialized for double"... Anyone?

Comment: `template<> void foo<double>(double bar);` But it is recommended not to specialize template functions: `void foo(double bar);`

Comment: The edited code require overloads of foo (for all the types), which the intention is to remove.

Comment: @UncleBens - Thanks for your comments, if I think about it, providing specializations for template functions is kind of paradox. 
But it's ok for templates classes I guess...At least I did learn something :-)

Answer (score 0):

To list an arbitrary selection of types I suppose you could use a typelist. E.g see the [last part of my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454905/force-type-of-c-template/2456031#2456031).

The usage might be something like:

```
//TODO: enhance typelist declarations to hide the recursiveness
typedef t_list<std::string, t_list<int> > good_for_foo; 

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if<in_type_list<T, good_for_foo> >::type foo(T t);
```