# In C++ what does template<> mean?

Tags: c++, templates

It's not a syntax I'm familiar with, but I saw it in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454905/force-type-of-c-template/2458547#2458547), an example being:

```
template<> struct Allowed<std::string> { };
```

What does `template<>` actually mean, with no template type/parameter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a specialization. `template<>` means that the specialization itself is not templated- i.e., it is an explicit specialization, not a partial specialization.

Comment: "template<> means that the specialization itself is not templated". This is not completely correct, as it applies only for that particular example. For instance: `template<typename T> struct A { template<typename U> void f(); }; template<> template<typename U> void A<int>::f() { }`. In this other example, the explicit specialization of the member is itself still a template. (It's a little bit nitpicking, but important to know).

Comment: I don't understand the answer.  Could you amend to show how it differentiates between partial and special?

Answer (score 50):

It is a template specialization. The typical case would be partial specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T1, class T2>
struct foo
{
  void doStuff() { std::cout << "generic foo "; }
};

template<class T1>
struct foo<T1, int>
{
 void doStuff() { std::cout << "specific foo with T2=int"; }
};
```

As you can see, the specialization removes one element from the template parameters and explicitly states a type instead of the removed one. That means if there is only one template type, the `<>` just become empty:

```
template<class T1>
struct bar
{
  void doStuff() { std::cout << "generic bar"; }
};

template<>
struct bar<int>
{
 void doStuff() { std::cout << "specific bar with T1=int"; }
};
```

Comment: then why use a template<> if it cant be general? Why not just make it a struct for int?

Comment: How to declare and call a specific bar with T1=int?

Comment: @P.S. Because you might want a version of your structure to exist for all non-specialisations.

Comment: Here are a few examples: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/8d08b103be936d78d5d4ed90c0547aeccb8ce166/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv_v7.cpp#L259

Comment: Does it make sense to have just the specializations but do do specify the general case? Like in https://youtu.be/oD1dvfbyf6A?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&t=1589. Why not just get rid of the template then?

Answer (score 12):

You might just say it is just the required syntax.

The normal syntax would be `template< typename T > struct Allowed`;

Because we know that in this case T is std::string there is nothing to put inside the angled brackets but the word template and the angled brackets are still required because writing
`struct Allowed<std::string>` on its own would not imply that you are specializing the template but simply that you are instantiating one with std::string as the type. (The word "struct" is not necessary to do that but is still permitted).