# What does a template class without arguments, `template<>` mean?

Tags: c++, templates

What does a template class without arguments mean? For example, let's take a template class who calculate factorial, whose template arguments in N - `N!`.

basically, this is the class:

```
template <int N> class Factorial
{
public:
    enum {fact = N * Factorial<N-1>::fact};
};
```

But, I found that the this class have an "extention class",

```
template<> class Factorial<1>
{
public:
    enum {fact = 1};
};
```

And here my question is: what does a template without arguments, `template<>` mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is template specialization

Comment: @aaronman: this is template *full* specialization. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++ what does template<> mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872809/in-c-what-does-template-mean)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This

```
template<> class Factorial<1>
{
public:
    enum {fact = 1};
};
```

is actually a *template **full** specialization* or *explicit specialization* of class template `Factorial`. There is also something called *template **partial** specialization*. Both are forms of [template specialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_specialization).

Template specializations are special cases wherein when you instantiate a template with the parameter indicated by the template specialization, that specific template specialization is used, instead of the original template.

In your code, the original `Factorial` template class

```
template <int N> class Factorial
{
public:
    enum {fact = N * Factorial<N-1>::fact};
};
```

is used when you instantiate, for example, the following:

- `Factorial<3>`
- `Factorial<5>`
- `Factorial<42>`

But when you instantiate/use

```
Factorial<1>
```

the template specialization `Factorial<1>` is used instead. In other words, it is a special case that is used whenever you supply `1` as the template parameter.

One notable example of a template specialization is [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), though [you must be careful whether to use it or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al).

[Also an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6b3b8aad37d3ee3bb3591544b96bda36-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51). That show's some minimal usage of template specializations for both class templates and function templates.

Comment: What do you mean by "template specialization"?

Comment: Amm , Ok , I've got your edit. Now everything make sense. very thank you!

Comment: @aaronman: technically it is *"template **full** specialization"*. I also edited the answer. and .... +1

Comment: @Nawaz both partial template specialization and template full specialization are forms of template specialization

Comment: @Nawaz That's better, but saying *"template specialization"* is still correct, as a full specialization is a template specialization.

Comment: @aaronman: Yes, but "template full specialization" is more specific, technically. Note that *template full specialization* is **not** a template anymore!

Comment: @Nawaz being unspecific isn't incorrect, anyway I should've answered I knew this was gonna be a big rep gainer

Comment: @aaronman: I didn't say it is incorrect. It is just "technically more specific and precise".

Comment: Also, "template full specialization" is also called **explicit specialization**. It is better to use more specific terminologies. It helps avoiding/removing confusion.