# What does `template<>` mean in front of a variable definition in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++98

I'm recently working on some legacy codes written in C++98.

I am trying to get them compiled by C++17 compiler. A whole lot of warnings popped out as I was doing that. However, almost all the warnings were easily resolved. Except for this one:

```cpp
struct Counter {
    Counter(int v) : m_val(v) {}
    int m_val;
};

struct AClass {
    static Counter SEQ;
};
   
template<> Counter AClass::SEQ = 0;
```

The C++17 compiler gave a warning "too many template headers for...(should be 0)" for the line `template<> Counter AClass::SEQ = 0;`. (https://godbolt.org/z/G845K3cvv)

But for C++98 compiler it was totally OK. (https://godbolt.org/z/xErje7T8o)

Now, in order to resolve the warning, I need a complete understanding as to what does the statement mean in the C++98 world.

My gut feeling is that it is a full template specialization. And the template argument is empty. So it is equivalent to `Counter AClass::SEQ = 0;` and `template<>` means nothing. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872816/1085251)

Can anyone tell me exactly what it means?

Comment: I don't think it's a Standard change. Might be a defect fix or or a bug in older compilers. Or since it's a warning and not a hard error, it might be something that's now reported and previously wasn't.

Comment: You get a warning with gcc 5.1 onwards. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxG15hxh4). Also the program is ill-formed.

Comment: It's a template specialisation.   I'd argue that the C++98 compiler was incorrect in not diagnosing an error since none of the types/objects in your sample are templates that need to be specialised.   (I'd also guess the `template<>` is either a typo, or an artefact resulting from editing a templated type to produced non-templated type).   You may wish to look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872809/in-c-what-does-template-mean

Comment: This is the emulation of `inline static Counter SEQ = 0;` in the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like gcc 4.7.4  is unable to give a diagnostic. Note that from gcc 5.1 onwards, we get a diagnostic from gcc. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W5T8hjWeK).

The given program is ill-formed in both C++17 as well as C++98 as you're trying to provide an **explicit specialization** when there is nothing to specialize(as there is no **templated entity** anywhere in the program and `AClass` is also not a class template).